# How can I be notified when a window is closed by window.close (javascript)?

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control

I've been asked to retro-fit a custom web-browser built around the IE 9 control. One of the requirements was that all pop-up windows must be caught and redirected into a new tab. The customer didn't want any floating stand-alone windows to appear.

The previous developer implemented the following function to capture these cases and open a new tab instead.

```
public void NewWindow3(ref object ppDisp, ref bool Cancel, uint dwFlags, string bstrUrlContext, string bstrUrl)
{
    BrowserExtendedNavigatingEventArgs args = new BrowserExtendedNavigatingEventArgs(ppDisp, new Uri(bstrUrl), null, (UrlContext)dwFlags);
    _Browser.OnStartNewWindow(args);
    Cancel = args.Cancel;
    ppDisp = args.AutomationObject;
}
```

The problem occurs when one of these opened windows expects to be able to call window.close from javascript.

I was hoping I could use this function

```
public void WindowClosing(bool isChildWindow, ref bool cancel)
```

to detect the javascript call and close the tab. But this function is never called. The javascript function itself seems to work. The contents of the tab are cleared. How can I detect this scenario and close the tab?

Note that the IE9 active x control is not a hard requirement. But please don't suggest I switch rendering engines solely for the sake of the purity of the internet :P.

EDIT:

Here is my definition of the DWebBrowserEvents2 interface in C#.

```
    [ComImport, TypeLibType((short)0x1010), InterfaceType((short)2), Guid("34A715A0-6587-11D0-924A-0020AFC7AC4D")]
    public interface DWebBrowserEvents2
    {
        [DispId(0x111)]
        void NewWindow3(
            [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] ref object ppDisp, 
            [In, Out] ref bool Cancel,
            [In] uint dwFlags, 
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string bstrUrlContext, 
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string bstrUrl);

        [DispId(253)]
        void OnQuit();

        [DispId(263)]
        void WindowClosing(
            [In] bool isChildWindow,
            [In, Out] ref bool cancel);

        [DispId(283)]
        void WindowStateChanged(
            [In] uint dwFlags,
            [In] uint dwVAlidFlagsMask);

        [DispId(271)]
        void NavigateError(
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] object pDisp,
            [In] ref object URL, [In] ref object frame,
            [In] ref object statusCode, [In, Out] ref bool cancel);
    }
```

Comment: Here's a sample page - http://www.javascript-coder.com/files/window-popup/javascript-window-close-example1.html.

But I'm not actually writing any particular pages to be used, I'm writing the browser itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found an answer here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/1cda7799-bf65-4c66-a3bf-488656998191 and it worked for me.

In case that link goes away, here's the answer from that page:

```
// A delegate type for hooking up close notifications.
public delegate void ClosingEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

// We need to extend the basic Web Browser because when a web page calls
// "window.close()" the containing window isn't closed.
public class ExtendedWebBrowser : WebBrowser
{
  // Define constants from winuser.h
  private const int WM_PARENTNOTIFY = 0x210;
  private const int WM_DESTROY = 2;

  public event ClosingEventHandler Closing;

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
  {
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
      case WM_PARENTNOTIFY:
        if (!DesignMode)
        {
          if (m.WParam.ToInt32() == WM_DESTROY)
          {
            Closing(this, EventArgs.Empty);
          }
        }
        DefWndProc(ref m);
        break;
      default:
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        break;
    }
  }
}

//Then your containing class has the following:
private ExtendedWebBrowser browserControl;
this.browserControl.Closing +=new ClosingEventHandler(browserControl_Closing);
private void browserControl_Closing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Close();
}
```

Comment: can you please help me with this old query - For me I am always getting m.WParam as LButtonDown {513}. How to get the window.close() event here I am unable to figure out.
User will be clicking a button in html page and that button onclick will be calling window.close event in javascript?