# C# - Close a System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser when the javascript on the webpage calls window.close()

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend

I'm launching a website on a C# System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser, and after performing the task on the website, the website's javascript calls a function consisting of this:

```
window.open("Closer.html", '_self');
```

Closer.html contains this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.close();
</script>
```

And this works perfectly on an external browser like IE or chrome. But my winforms browser remains open. I have researched this and found that others have experienced this problem, and have been unable to find a solution.

I'd like to either have my C# System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser class detect that the javascript function window.close() has been called and subsequently do a simple this.close() call, or I could modify the javascript Closer.html to close the System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser window if that can be done.

Comment: And, you don't have access to the html file correct? To change the javascript or html?

Comment: Actually, yea, I have access to the html files entirely.

Comment: Ok, just trying to think of options. What about hooking up to the Navigating event and checking the url for "Closer.html"?

Comment: That sounds good. I'm not exactly familiar with the Navigating event tho. and on the Winforms browser, when I expect it to call the Closer.html, it appears to remain on the original webpage. This browser will not perform any navigation during it's use outside of calling the Closer.html as described in the op.

Comment: See my post and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out. Set your browser to allow navigation. Either from designer or via code.

```
wb.AllowNavigation = true;
```

Then, see if this event is fired:

```
private void wb_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Url.AbsolutePath.IndexOf("closer.html", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 1)
        this.Close();
}
```

Obviously, you need to hook up the navigating event. Again, via the designer or via code.

```
wb.Navigating += wb_Navigating;
```

---

Edit: That should work for your specific case, however I do see a good answer posted here to a similar issue.

[How can I be notified when a window is closed by window.close (javascript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101113/how-can-i-be-notified-when-a-window-is-closed-by-window-close-javascript?rq=1)

Using the code found there, and modifying the html, you should be able to handle this. Instead of doing the redirect, you COULD just call window.close(). Then, the webbrowser should notice and act accordingly.

Comment: This appears to work flawlessly. I'll be testing it throughout the day tomorrow and will keep you posted. Thanks infinitely for this help!

Comment: No problem. Good luck!